# Create a new high level folder in TFS without downloading all project using Team Explorer Everywhere command line Linux

Tags: linux, git, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere, git-tf

I want to add new folder to TFS that will contain a new project. I'm using "[Team Explorer Everywhere 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785)" for Linux.

The folder structure is like the following

```
$Main\HighLevelFolder\Project1
$Main\HighLevelFolder\Project2
...
$Main\HighLevelFolder\ProjectN
```

I want to add a new folder, e.g. `$Main\HighLevelFolder\ProjectX` in the most efficient way.

I can either checkout the entire `$Main\HighLevelFolder` and create a new project folder in it, and check it back in. But there are quite a lot of projects. I would rather create the folder on the server, then checkout just the folder.

(I am actually using [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) for checkout/checkin against the TFS server.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/641987/1336249 Gives me a hint:

```
.. map the server-side folder to a workspace on your local machine ...
```

But it's not clear how to do that under the TEE command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git-TF does not require a folder to have been created in TFS already.

`git tf configure http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/Path/To/{folder}`

`git tf checkin --deep`

And the new project folder is created